# How can I save Perl/Expect output that contains mixed ascii content?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, expect, text-processing

I have a perl script that uses the expect library to login to a remote system. I'm getting the final output of the interaction with the before method:

```
$exp->before();
```

I'm saving this to a text file. When I use cat on the file it outputs fine in the terminal, but when I open the text file in an editor or try to process it the formatting is bizarre:

> [H[2J[1;19HCIRCULATION ACTIVITY by TERMINAL (Nov 6,14)[11;1H

Is there a better way to save the output?

When I run enca it's identified as:

> 7bit ASCII characters
>
> Surrounded by/intermixed with non-text data

Comment: What you are seeing are ANSI escape codes.  If you set your TERM environment variable to something that doesn't understand them, they will likely not be generated.

Comment: Thanks, now I know what direction I need to go in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the ANSI escape codes from my output by using the Text::ANSI::Util library's ta_strip() function:

```
my $ansi_string = $exp->before();
my $clean_string = ta_strip($ansi_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove none ascii chars.

```
$str1 =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]//g;
print "$str1\n";
```

Comment: ANSI escape codes have the interesting property of being made up entirely of ASCII characters.  Have you tried your solution to see what change it makes to the OP's sample string?